# ArrayList is empty after session sets the attribute

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, arraylist, el

I have debugged this and I can see that the ArrayList is being filled up with the proper entries, but the EL is not picking up the list to display in the web page. The exact code for the session.setAttribute for the worked previously but now it doesn't. The attributes for the values from the previous page are set but the forEach table isn't. In the debug, or if you press F12, it shows that the attributen 'propertyListings' has x amount of objects in the array, but they are blank, showing as [ , , , , , , ]. Not sure what I messed up on. Thanks in advance.

I am using NetBeans 8.2 and the server is Tomcat.

THE SERVLET: Searching.java

package ServletTasks;

```
import Business.Inventory;
import Business.Property;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author ti488678
 */
@WebServlet(name = "Searching", urlPatterns = {"/Searching"})
public class Searching extends HttpServlet {


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    processRequest(request, response);

}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    double searchLow =  Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("searchLow"));
    double searchHigh = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("searchHigh"));

    String url = "/index.jsp";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

     if (action == null) {
        action = "search";  // default action
    }

    // perform action and set URL to appropriate page
    if (action.equals("search")) {



        url = "/searched.jsp";

        Inventory inventory = new Inventory();

        inventory.setAllProperties();

        session.setAttribute("lowSearch", searchLow);
        session.setAttribute("highSearch", searchHigh);
        ArrayList<Property> propertyList = inventory.search(searchLow, searchHigh);

        session.setAttribute("propertyListings", propertyList);

        getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher(url)
            .forward(request, response);
    }

}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {

    return "Short description";

}

}
```

WEB PAGE: index.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Foreal Estate</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    </head>

    <header>
        <h2>FoReal Estate</h2>
    </header>

    <main id="wrapper">

        <h4>Search: Enter low and high values to search for a property</h4>
        <form action="Searching" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search"> 
            <label for="searchLow">Low Value</label>
            <input type="text" name="searchLow" value="">
            <br><br>
            <label for="searchHigh">High Value</label>
            <input type="text" name="searchHigh" value="">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Search">
        </form>

        <br><br><br><br>


    </main>

</html>
```

WEB PAGE: searched.jsp

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : searched
    Created on : Feb 8, 2017, 3:45:56 PM
    Author     : MyPC
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

        <title>Searching Properties</title>
    </head>

<header>
    <h2>Search Criteria: $${lowSearch} to $${highSearch}</h2>
</header>

<main id="wrapper">

    <h2>Listings:</h2>

     <table>
        <c:forEach var="property" items="${propertyListings}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${property.address}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${property.price}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>

</main>
```

THE XML: web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

JAVA CLASS: Inventory.java

```
package Business;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.*;

public class Inventory implements Serializable{

    ArrayList<Property> propertyList = new ArrayList<Property>();

    public Inventory() {

    }

    public void setAllProperties() {
        Property p = new Property();
        p.setAddress("87 Ford Rd");
        p.setPrice(2200000.00);
        p.setSquareFeet(2000);
        p.setTaxes(7000.00);
        p.setYearBuilt(LocalDate.of(1865, Month.APRIL, 15));
        p.setListingDate(LocalDate.now().minusYears(2));

        addProperty(p);

        Property p2 = new Property();
        p2.setAddress("36 Grassy Knoll");
        p2.setPrice(120000.00);
        p2.setSquareFeet(2000);
        p2.setTaxes(2200.00);
        p2.setYearBuilt(LocalDate.of(1963, Month.NOVEMBER, 22));
        p2.setListingDate(LocalDate.now().minusWeeks(2));

        addProperty(p2);

        Property p3 = new Property();
        p3.setAddress("223 Oak St");
        p3.setPrice(190000.00);
        p3.setSquareFeet(4000);
        p3.setTaxes(2600.00);
        p3.setYearBuilt(LocalDate.of(1901, Month.SEPTEMBER, 14));
        p3.setListingDate(LocalDate.now().minusMonths(2));

        addProperty(p3);

        Property p4 = new Property();
        p4.setAddress("13 Foster Lane");
        p4.setPrice(110000.00);
        p4.setSquareFeet(2500);
        p4.setTaxes(1800.00);
        p4.setYearBuilt(LocalDate.of(1981, Month.MARCH, 30));
        p4.setListingDate(LocalDate.now().minusDays(2));

        addProperty(p4);

        Property p5 = new Property();
        p5.setAddress("15 Foster Lane");
        p5.setPrice(115000.00);
        p5.setSquareFeet(2500);
        p5.setTaxes(1800.00);
        p5.setYearBuilt(LocalDate.of(1981, Month.JUNE, 22));
        p5.setListingDate(LocalDate.now().minusDays(2));

        addProperty(p5);

        Property p6 = new Property();
        p6.setAddress("782 Butler Ave");
        p6.setPrice(105000.00);
        p6.setSquareFeet(1800);
        p6.setTaxes(1900.00);
        p6.setYearBuilt(LocalDate.of(1999, Month.FEBRUARY, 01));
        p6.setListingDate(LocalDate.now().minusDays(2));

        addProperty(p6);

        Property p7 = new Property();
        p7.setAddress("70 Martel Road");
        p7.setPrice(285000.00);
        p7.setSquareFeet(3500);
        p7.setTaxes(2800.00);
        p7.setYearBuilt(LocalDate.of(2012, Month.MARCH, 15));
        p7.setListingDate(LocalDate.now().minusDays(2));

        addProperty(p7);

        Property p8 = new Property();
        p8.setAddress("40th Sister Brook");
        p8.setPrice(450000.00);
        p8.setSquareFeet(4400);
        p8.setTaxes(3720.00);
        p8.setYearBuilt(LocalDate.of(2015, Month.JULY, 01));
        p8.setListingDate(LocalDate.now().minusDays(2));

        addProperty(p8);

        Property p9 = new Property();
        p9.setAddress("405 Nebraska Street");
        p9.setPrice(108980.00);
        p9.setSquareFeet(1500);
        p9.setTaxes(1350.00);
        p9.setYearBuilt(LocalDate.of(1950, Month.JANUARY, 03));
        p9.setListingDate(LocalDate.now().minusDays(2));

        addProperty(p9);

        Property p10 = new Property();
        p10.setAddress("1455 Roca Road");
        p10.setPrice(423055.00);
        p10.setSquareFeet(3750);
        p10.setTaxes(3860.00);
        p10.setYearBuilt(LocalDate.of(1995, Month.NOVEMBER, 28));
        p10.setListingDate(LocalDate.now().minusDays(2));

        addProperty(p10);

    }

    public ArrayList<Property> getProperties() {
        setAllProperties();
        return propertyList;
    }

    public void addProperty(Property property) {
        propertyList.add(property);
    }

    public Property getProperty(int index) {
        if (index >= 0) {
            return (Property) propertyList.get(index);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int numberOfProperties() {
        return propertyList.size();
    }


    public ArrayList<Property> search(double lowPrice, double highPrice) {

        ArrayList<Property> matchingList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Property p : propertyList) {
            if(p.getPrice() >= lowPrice && p.getPrice() <= highPrice) {
                matchingList.add(p);
            }
        }

        return matchingList;
    }
}
```

JAVA CLASS: Property.java

```
package Business;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;

public class Property implements Serializable{

    private String address;
    private int squareFeet;
    private double price;
    private LocalDate yearBuilt;
    private LocalDate listingDate;
    private double taxes;

    public Property() {
        address = "000 default st";
        squareFeet = 128;
        price = 2048;
        yearBuilt = LocalDate.of(1970, Month.JANUARY, 1);
        listingDate = yearBuilt.plusYears(5);
        taxes = 16;
    }

    public Property(String address, int squareFeet,
            double price, LocalDate yearBuilt, LocalDate listingDate, double taxes) {
        this.address = address;
        this.squareFeet = squareFeet;
        this.price = price;
        this.yearBuilt = yearBuilt;
        this.listingDate = listingDate;
        this.taxes = taxes;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setSquareFeet(int squareFeet) {
        this.squareFeet = squareFeet;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setYearBuilt(LocalDate yearBuilt) {
        this.yearBuilt = yearBuilt;
    }

    public void setTaxes(double taxes) {
        this.taxes = taxes;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return (this.address);
    }

    public int getSquareFeet() {
        return (this.squareFeet);
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return (this.price);
    }

    public LocalDate getYearBuilt() {
        return (this.yearBuilt);
    }

    public LocalDate getListingDate() {
        return (this.listingDate);
    }

    public double getTaxes() {
        return (this.taxes);
    }

    public void setListingDate(LocalDate listingDate) {
        this.listingDate = listingDate;
    }

    //Optional complete this method to build a String that contains all of the house's information for easy display
    //it would be better to use the EL output each property's properties
    public String toString() {
        String ifYouBuildIt = "";

        return ifYouBuildIt;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `toString()` method returns an empty string. That's why you're seeing  `[ , , , , , , ]`.

Comment: Why does the toString get called if I never explicitly call it? Why doesn't get table get populated?